# Rate for a novice building a Wordpress site

Tags: pay-rate, web-development, working-from-home

I hope this is the right place to ask this question- and I'll try to be detailed and yet brief.

I am a recent college graduate with a degree in Web Technologies. I have been approached by a family friend with some website help. She wants to upgrade her shop's site. Most likely, I would use Wordpress- since I am familiar with that system. She runs an instrument repair/school band accessory shop. Ideally, she would like it completed at the end of this month. She wants it to look more like https://www.straitmusic.com/.

My question is- what is a good rate quote I would be able to give her? I am very new to the freelance field and don't have much "real-world" experience. Being a family friend as well- I would want to give her some sort of "discount." I would be interested more so in a flat-rate fee, so I wouldn't have to worry about tracking hours worked and all that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one can price anything for you. For more info [see here](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/it-is-valid-to-ask-how-and-how-much-to-charge-for-some-things)

Comment: Thank you for that information, @Scott. I figured there would be many different variables at play that would make it difficult to answer my question properly.

Comment: Price is so very *specific* to an individual that no one can feasibly just give you **accurate** rates. Anyone claiming they know, doesn't. Although in a slightly different field, if you look [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/959/3270) at the highly up voted answer (which was never accepted), that's how you price essentially - via a formula based upon *your* expenses and overhead, then *your* experience and skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of project -- given your experience level and the fact that it's a family friend you know and trust -- I'd suggest starting by offering your services at an hourly rate.

While hourly may not always be the best way to price your services, here I think it makes sense. You don't yet reasonably know how long this job will take you, since you don't have experience. Doing it with a flat fee you'll most likely end up working for an insanely low rate. So by doing hourly and not asking for a horrendous rate from the family friend, you can get your feet wet and create value for your customer while at the same time learning and earning decent money. If you're US based, I'd say ask for a $30/hr rate and be honest with your customer: You're fresh out of college, you've good training, but you're inexperienced and want to learn, so you're offering your services at a sub-market rate. I'd think the market rate for Wordpress dev is >$40-$50/hr min.